# Update information on other screen

Tags: kindle

I need to show one html file in public places (restaurants — mealtime menu).

For example, this file have address http://example.com/today-menu.html

What reader better to use (kindle or other) to automatic update this menu once a day?
Is it possible with wifi update — checking once in 10 minutes for example?

I need cheapest variant (cheap reader, energy saving - connects to wifi once in 10 minutes for example) and make it 100% automatic.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">`. Just place that in your `<head />`

`content` specifies how often to refresh in seconds.

This should let any standards compliant browser automatically refresh the page.

Comment: Yes. I need explain from other hand — cheapest reader and with wifi support. Best solution: 1) reader connects to wifi once; 2) check page for changes; 3) update; 4) disconnect. Configurable time — 10 minutes; 60 minutes or other

Comment: As long as your page is a simple HTML page, there is no way to check for updates, you have to reload the page. If you set content variable above to 600 it will refresh every 10 minutes. It should work on kindle browser. This method has been around for ages.

Comment: I can create other request with md5 sum (or something) and then refresh page. 
But this is not energy saving, because need connection to wifi all time.

Comment: Doing a request to get a checksum to compare or getting the whole page will not differ that much in either power consumed or time taken. For what you want to do you will always require a network connection, however you solve it. Perhaps that there is some obscure way to initiate a wifi connection only when needed, but then the solution will not be simple anymore.